# Necessary and sufficient so that $\left\lfloor {\frac{a}{N}} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor {\frac{b}{N}} \right\rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given a positive integer $N$, find the sufficient and necessary conditions for any non-negative integers $a,b$ so that
$$\left\lfloor {\frac{a}{N}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\frac{b}{N}} \right\rfloor$$

In fact, I'm trying to **lineairise** this equation for my bigger problem where $a,b$ must stay in the same segment of length $N$.

It is easy to see that $a - b \le N - 1$ and $a - b \ge -N + 1$, but I'm still unable to eliminate the case where $a,b$ are on the opposite side of $kN$, for example $a = N-1, b=N + 1$.

PS: I already know creating another integer $k$ so that $kN \le a, b < (k + 1) N$ but I'd like find another way without creating new unknown.

Comment: Necessary and sufficient conditions, how about "*There exists an integer $q$ such that $qN\leq a<(q+1)N$ and $qN\leq b<(q+1)N$*"?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining further. That was obvious and I'm trying to avoid that approach.

Comment: I doubt you can say anything further.  If you are looking just at the differences of $a$ and $b$, that is not enough information for exactly the reason you cite.  Some examples of where $a-b=1$ have the floors give the same value while other examples where $a-b=1$ have the floors give different values.

Comment: That's why i'm interested more in the case of integers, which might provide some more constraints over the "distancing".

Comment: Offering as comment, rather than answer, because it doesn't say much.  Let $\{x\}$ denote fractional part of $x$.  Then $a - \{a\} = \lfloor a\rfloor = \lfloor b\rfloor = b - \{b\} \iff [(a-b) = \{a\} - \{b\}].$